# Kinesis Firehose after COPY query

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I have Kinesis Firehose feeding data into Redshift. My data has an IP Address string field, and I use a second integer ip address column for geolocation purposes that is not in my source data. I'd like to run an update query every time the COPY finishes to update the integer ip columns from the string ip column where the integer one is null.

Is there a way to run a query after a load? Some other way to schedule a recurring query without introducing an ec2 instance for that?

Comment: UDF - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html ?

Comment: @Guy I have written a UDF in python to do the actual parsing, that's not a problem. The problem is I have to manually trigger the parsing for now. I want it automated.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something basic, but you don't need to trigger the calculation of the UDF. If you have a function that that is calculating a value based on the integer, you don't need to run any UNDATE command.

Comment: You're missing something in my question. I have 2 columns, it's an optimization. Parsing an ip address is expensive when you're talking about billions of rows.

Comment: You could try a scheduled lambda, but your minimum recurring period would be 5 min

Comment: @BryanPedlar post that as an answer and i'll mark it as answered